# iis6 multisite and permissions

Tags: multisite, permissions, iis

For testing mobile themes and other reasons, I am trying to use an existing server with wordpress setup as multisite.

The root site is not in inetpub/wwwroot but rather on another partition and that seems to work.
I want to the site to be conventionally http://somesite.com and http://somesite.com/mobile

I can see that the tables are created in the db when I add the other site, but not corresponding directories of /wpadmin, /wp-content, or /wp-includes get created anywhere.
I guess I am not sure where they should get created, and what permissions I would need on that directory.

I have tried using IIRF to get around the .htaccess rewrite issue, (I think) but since the correct sub-directories never get created, there is nothing to redirect to.

What have I done wrong? Is it not possible to have the base site in /? but not in /inetpub/wwwroot/?

I hope this is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not that there was a permissions issue.
Since iis6 doesn't use .htaccess it required installing [Ionics Isapi Rewriter](http://iirf.codeplex.com/)

Enabled on the webserver you then insert essentially the same content as a the .htaccess file into an iirf.ini file in the root of the site you want and the content becomes available.
Much simpler than I was trying originally.